# Does Android Activity Class violates with Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: android, architecture, solid-principles

As the definition of Single responsibility:

> Class (object) should have one and only one responsibility (and this
>   responsibility should be fully encapsulated)

or simply

> A class should have only one reason to change.

That is a very famous and important principle in the programming world. However, when looking at the design of Android Activity, as my point of view, Activity has more than one responsibility

- It manages the attached windows, dialogs, action bar, menu
- It handles instance state
- It manages keyboard
- It handles the logic of configuration change
- It provides cursor for getting data
- Etc

And as I see in so many tutorials, blog, GitHub open source, people also use Activity for inflating view.

Then my question is: does android activity class violate with Single Responsibility Principle?

Comment: `Activity` extends `Context` class which is a [God Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) - welcome to the real world... ;-(